# Application recent files on Windows Start Menu

Tags: c#, winforms

When an application icon is displayed on the windows start menu, if you hover the mouse cursor over the right arrow indicator shown, Windows displays all documents recently opened by the application.

How do I make my own application do this?

The functionality is the same as installed versions of Visual Studio and Adobe Reader.

Comment: have you tried anything?Also please rephrase your question it does not make sense.

Comment: Not really the correct place to be asking

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990369(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: related: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg281362.aspx

Comment: @Jackhardcastle why you guys down vote my question ?? i think this is the right place for this question. if you don't know the point then stay away from the question rather then down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the application, register a file type within Windows and add an "open" verb to the file type pointing at your application's executable file.

WiX is an installer framework that can do this. Have a look at this answer for how to add the "open" verb in WiX: [Wix File Association with standard Windows File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901285/wix-file-association-with-standard-windows-file)